# Angular Counter with limitTo and filter Issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am wanting to put a counter at the bottom of a table that displays something along the lines of "Displaying 100 of 250 names."  Currently, I have a search bar and automatically limit what is displayed to 100 when the page loads.

Here is the code that I have right now.

```
<tr ng-repeat="names in pool" |filter:searchNames | limitTo:100"
... 
<p> Displaying {{(pool|filter:searchNames).length}} of {{pool.lenght}} names. </p>
```

Instead of getting "Displaying 100 of 250 names." I am getting "Displaying 250 of 250 names.".  I am guessing that this is due to the fact that I am using filter:searchNames to get the first piece of data.

Can anyone help me out on how to display the number that I am using in the limitTo in case the query is larger than what is being displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out pretty quickly.  All I needed to do was put in the limitTo:100 like below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="names in pool" |filter:searchNames | limitTo:100"
... 
<p> Displaying {{(pool|filter:searchNames|limitTo:100).length}} of {{pool.lenght}} names. </p>
```